# How to achieve this horizontal grid in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

*Is there any way to achieve this UI in flutter, images are calling by an API, Card sizes are fixed. This should be scroll horizontally same as this. My code is down below*

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
            axisDirection: AxisDirection.right,
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4,
            children: const [
              StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1,
                mainAxisCellCount: 2,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 50,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1,
                mainAxisCellCount: 1,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 50,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1,
                mainAxisCellCount: 1,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 50,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1,
                mainAxisCellCount: 1,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 50,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1,
                mainAxisCellCount: 2,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 50,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 2,
                mainAxisCellCount: 1,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 50,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

I tried with mentioned code & I attached the result as well, I use Staggered GridView to implement this

[image]

My code output [image: I just wanted to do is loop this grid]

I just wanted to do is loop this grid and add images to tiles.

Comment: check `flutter_staggered_grid_view` package

Comment: @YeasinSheikh have you ever tried with it?

Comment: I think it should solve your case, perhaps you can include the methods you’ve tried so far. If it fails, custom Card layout can be placed on PageView/ListView...

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you check my updated comment?

Answer (score 0):

[the layout will always considered a top-to-bottom and left-to-right directions to simplify the description. However it is possible to change these directions in the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjXzG.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```dart
ListView(
  // This next line does the trick.
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[ /* your widgets */],
),
```

or as already pointed out in a comment, use the package `flutter_staggered_grid_view`

Comment: My question is not to implement only a horizontal view, I just want to know a way to build UI like I posted. Thanks

Comment: @achinthaishane he mentioned to you to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view